# Abstract classes - C'tor , D'tor and operator=

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, abstract-class

While we talks about abstract class , how I need to refer about `d'tor` , `c'tor` and `operator=`?

(Namely, how these methods defined for abstract-class, I can implement them for abstract class? Exists cases so that it's necessary to implement the for abstract class?)

I asks this question because that we can't to create objects from type of abstract class, hence, I don't sure how it's affect about the methods written above (maybe exists special rules about these methods, and hence, I ask this question).

Comment: It really depends on the use-case. A pure interface class (a class which have *only* pure abstract functions declarations) won't need any of those. Otherwise don't forget to consider [the rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Yes, you *can* implement them for an abstract class, if needed.    Practically, it is rarely necessary, as the compiler-generated defaults (which can be forced using `= default` in C++11 and later) are often sufficient.  For a pure interface class (which contain virtual member functions and no data members) the defaults will be enough.   For an abstract class that explicitly manages dynamic memory allocation (e.g. a pure virtual member function, and a data member that is a pointer) rather than using other classes to do that, it will probably be necessary to follow the rule of three or five.